# Front Page not showing on Pages

Tags: pages

Newbie here.  I set my Front page to show my latest posts using Settings/Reading.  However, the Front page itself doesn't show up in Pages, which is preventing me from doing some editing (using Beaver Builder plugin).  Is this normal, and if not, is there a way that I get the Front page to show in my list of pages?

Comment: hello there just change your file name, you should change home to another any name. like welcome, main, and etc.

Comment: but I would like the blog to be on the homepage and not separately, so what do I do in that case?

Answer (score 3):

This is normal. To display your posts, `index.php` is being used. It is not a regular page created by you. Some call it a virtual page. If you want all posts being displayed on a page created by you, follow these steps:

1. prepare two pages. One for front page, and second for posts ( you can title them `Home`, and `Blog` - their names are up to you )
2. go to `Settings -> Reading -> Front page displays`, and select `A static page (select below)`. From a drop down list of pages, choose `Home`, from your previous step. From the second drop down list, choose Blog, from previous step
3. Save your changes

Now `Home` will be your front page, and `Blog` will be showing all posts.